# Creating mp4 file doesn't remove tmp files

Tags: java, spring-boot, io, temporary-files

I'm trying to write an InputStream that is an mp4  that I get from calling an external SOAP service, when I do so, it always generates this tmp files for my chosen temporary directory(java.io.tmpdir) that aren't removable and stay after the writing is done.

Writing images that I also get from the SOAP service works normal without the permanent tmp on the directory. I'm using java 1.8 SpringBoot

[tmp files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5ztC.png)

This is what I'm doing:

```
File targetFile = new File("D:/archive/video.mp4");
targetFile.getParentFile().mkdirs(); 
targetFile.setWritable(true);

InputStream inputStream = filesToWrite.getInputStream();
OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(targetFile);

                    try {

                        int byteRead;

                        while ((byteRead = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
                            outputStream.write(byteRead);
                        }

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        logger.fatal("Error@ SaveFilesThread for guid:  " + guid, e);
                    }finally {
                        try {
                            inputStream.close();
                            outputStream.flush();
                            outputStream.close();

                        }catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

also tried:

```
byte data[] = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
Path file = Paths.get("video.mp4");
Files.write(file, data);
```

And from apache commons IO:

```
 FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(initialStream, targetFile);
```

Answer (score -1):

When your code starts, the damage is already done. Your code is not the source of the temporary files (It's.. a ton of work for something that could be done so much simpler, though, see below), it's the framework that ends up handing you that `filesToWrite` variable.

It is somewhat likely that you can hook in at an earlier point and get the raw inputstream representing the socket or HTTP connection, and start saving the files straight from there. Alternatively, Perhaps `filesToWrite` has a way to get at the files themselves, in which case you can just move them into place instead of copying them over.

But, your code to do this is a mess, it has bad exception handling, and leaks memory, and is way too much code for a simple job, and is possibly 2000x to 10000x slower than needed depending on your harddisk (I'm not exaggerating, calling single-byte `read()` on unbuffered streams is thousands of times slower!)

```
// add `throws IOException` to your method signature.
// it saves files, it's supposed to throw IOException,
// 'doing I/O' is in the very definition of your method!

try (InputStream in = filesToWrite.getInputStream();
  OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(targetFile)) {

    in.transferTo(out);
}
```

That's it. That solves all the problems - no leaks, no speed loss, tiny amount of code, fixes the deplorable error handling (which, here, is 'log something to the log, then print something to standard out, then potentially leak a bunch of resources, then don't tell the calling code anything went wrong and return exactly as if the copy operation succeeded).

Comment: That solution didn't work.This was actually an example desperate for a different resolution. Bellow you can see I also used apache commons IO.

Comment: It's not a solution, it was a sidenote of how you can do this safer, easier, and without depending on old libraries with pretty bad API design: Reread this answer, it explains that the code you pasted starts running when the temp files have already been made, and you need to look elsewhere. If you  can't find it, make a new question or thoroughly update this one: Explain what 'filesToWrite' is and where that came from.

Comment: The tmp files aren't made before this code, it only appears when the FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFil().  FilesToWrite is what comes from the SOAP service.

Comment: It is impossible for the code that I gave you, to produce those temp files, unless the input stream that `filesToWrite.getInputStream` produces makes them in which case there is still not one iota you can do about it here - you'd have to edit that code or use something else.

Comment: Yes impossible but it's happening,  I did a Break Point and only after  FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFil() they are generated, same with the code you provided. 

You are saying that the input stream somehow has instructions to write tmp files?
The same line of code(yours and mine) also writes an inputStream from the service which are jpgs and no tmp are generated, only happens with the mp4 inputStream.

Comment: InputStream is an abstraction. You can make an InputStream which will play Lady Gaga on every 12th download byte if you'd want to.